# How do I know what type / line of code is causing template warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting the following warning:

```
JUCE\modules\juce_core\containers\juce_ArrayBase.h(155): warning C4723: potential divide by 0
```

The offending line of code looks like this:

```
return isPositiveAndBelow (index, numUsed) ? elements[index] : ElementType();
```

No division there. So it must be an issue with the type that is being compiled with the template.

isPositiveAndBelow doesn't divide either.

```
template <typename Type>
bool isPositiveAndBelow (int valueToTest, Type upperLimit) noexcept
{
    jassert (upperLimit >= 0); // makes no sense to call this if the upper limit is itself below zero..
    return static_cast<unsigned int> (valueToTest) < static_cast<unsigned int> (upperLimit);
}
```

How do I find either, what type is causing the warning? Or what line of code in my code is triggering the warning?

Comment: I've updated the question with the implementation of `isPositiveAndBelow`

Comment: From [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4723?view=vs-2019): "The compiler may have generated the zero operand." so that's pretty frustrating

Comment: You can look into disassembly to see where is that division. If you can put a reduced example on https://godbolt.org/ that reproduced this warning, someone can help explaining that division. Or if you can put disassembly of actual code, someone can help explaining the division either.

Comment: I can see the following potentially dividing operation that can be present here: (1) `index` to `int` if `index` is some type with conversion operator. (2) the same for `numUsed` to `unsigned int` (3) `elements[index]`, if `operator[]` is not pointer/array indexing. (4) `ElementType()` construction. (5) `return` statement itself if it performs copy or move.  I'm sure I have not listed everything, a lot can happen behind the scenes for user defined types.